# How to add a base field for an entity reference to a specific vocabulary

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, entities

I have an Entity: `EntityX`.  It installs correctly and works the way that I want it to; with, of course, one exception.

I want to attach an entity reference to a specific vocabulary.  I have tried:

My vocabulary's machine name is: `custom_vocabulary`

In `EntityX`'s definition I have the following defined in the `baseFieldDefinitions` function:

```
$fields['my_custom_vocabulary'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Vocabulary'))
  ->setDescription(t('What was this tagged with.'))
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'custom_vocabulary')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'author',
    'weight' => -3,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'settings' => array(
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => 60,
      'placeholder' => '',
    ),
    'weight' => -3,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

But when I go to install it, I get the following error:

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "custom_vocabulary" entity type does not exist. in /brew/www/html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php:133
```

While looking at the article defined in the `installation profile` for Drupal, I see that they use it as a field and not a true entity reference.  Is there no way for me to do it this way?  I can't have this all nicely bundled into one single entity.

What I don't know how to do is add a term from a vocabulary to an entity type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vocabularies are bundles of the entity type taxonomy term. If you want to reference a vocabulary then first set `taxonomy_term` as target type and second restrict the field to a specific vocabulary as target bundle:

```
$definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['custom_vocabulary' => 'custom_vocabulary']]);
```

See change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2576151